# ColumnTransformer Passthrough not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, data-science

I wanted to standardize the values in my pandas dataframe, and keep one column of values the same so I used `ColumnTransformer`. However, it seems like the function isn't passing over the column I want it to pass over. `df` is my dataframe, here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

physical_vars = ["DPhill", "DYjj", "mjj", "mll", "mT", "ptTot", "sumOfCentralitiesL", "mL1J1", "mL1J2", "mL2J1", "mL2J2", "ptJ1", "ptJ2", "ptJ3", "METSig"]
other_vars = ["eventNumber", "weight"]
full_var_list =  other_vars + physical_vars

ct = ColumnTransformer([('Standardizer', StandardScaler(), full_var_list)],'passthrough')

col_names=full_var_list
col_names.append("ProcessID")
tmp_df=df[col_names]
standardized_values=ct.fit_transform(tmp_df) #np_array

df=pd.DataFrame(standardized_values,columns=full_var_list)
```

I want to pass over the "ProcessID" column, but when I print out that column the values are standardized.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you first modificate column list and then apply column transformer. You can check

```
test = ['column1', 'column2']
col_names = test
col_names.append('column3')
test
```

You can see that `test` also contains 'column3'. You should create copy of initial list and then modificate this copy:

```
test = ['column1', 'column2']
col_names = test.copy()
col_names.append('column3')
test
```

Now `test` doesn't contain 'column3' and `ColumnTransformer` will work as expected.